# AccessKey no Jquery

Tags: jquery

Em uma página tenho diversos botões com seus respectivos accesskey (tecla de atalho para o mesmo), como faço para quando esse botão for chamado pela tecla executar a ação click do mesmo no Jquery. Exemplo: tenho o botão Enviar, com atalho pela tecla A, quando pressiono a tecla A (accesskey do mesmo) chamo a função de click do botão no Jquery.

Comment: Se puder, comente o codigo que está utilizando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei exatamente como estás a adicionar esses aucultadores de eventos. Se adicionares isso na pergunta fica mais claro a tua tua implementação.

Alguns exemplos de como podes fazer isso:

#### Se estiveres a adicionar localmente

se o que usas é algo do género: `$('.button').on('click, keyup', function(){` então podes juntar uma verificação do tipo de evento assim:

```
$('.button').on('click, keyup', function(e){
    if (e.key == 13){
        // correr a lógica do código para a tecla Enter, e depois
        $(this).click();
    }
    // etc
```

ou alternativamente `if (e.type != 'click') $(this).click();`, mas se já tens uma lógica para detetar a tecla isso implica que é um evento de teclas.

#### Se tens um auscultador global

Se tens algo do género `$(document).on('keyup', function(){` que vai verificar qual a tecla então deves ter um objeto que guarde a relação entre botões e teclas... por exemplo:

Botão 1

e depois podes colocar isso em cache no inicio do carregamento da página:

```
var btnsTeclas = {};
$('button[data-tecla]').each(function(){
    var tecla = $(this).data('tecla');
    btnsTeclas[tecla] = this;
});
```

e quando souberes qual é a tecla basta fazeres:

```
var teclaPressionada = event.key; // ou outra lógica que tenhas para saber a tecla pressionada
$(btnsTeclas[teclaPressionada]).click();
```